# IBM mobilefirst direct update failed in Cordova android application

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I'm facing an issue with Direct Update on the Android app with IBM MFP Worklight 8.0

The app is getting an update after web resources are deployed. But after the apk receives an update, and user clicks on it - "Direct Update Failure" is shown. Some user are getting this issue.

Version details:

cordova-plugin-mfp - 8.0.2019091217

Please guide me find the solution.